# how to set default value of a dropdownlist in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to set the default value of a dropdownlist (UpdateDistributor) in vb.

UpdateDistributor.DataValueField doesn't seem to work. The drop down list remained blank

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    If Not IsPostBack Then
       Dim TitleSearch As String = "Select distrubtorcode from titles where isbn = 986765654"
       Dim table As DataTable = Database.SelectRows(TitleSearch)

       If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            UpdateDistributor.DataValueField = table.rows(0)("distrubtorcode")
       End if 

    End if 

    Dim SQLUpdateDistrubtor =  "Select distinct distrubtorcode from titles "
    MyData = Database.SelectRows(SQLUpdateDistrubtor)
    For Each Row As DataRow In MyData.Rows
        UpdateDistributor.Items.Add(New ListItem((Row)("companyname"), (Row)("companyname")))
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: So your `ValueField` you want to be `distrubtorcode` and what is seen in the combobox should be `companyname` ?

Comment: my apologies - only distributor code. just edited it. I'm hoping to grab the distributor code of a specific isbn to show as the value field and what is seen in the combo box is a list of distinct distributor codes from the database.

Comment: The list in the combox works fine - I'm having problem with setting the default value. I know with a textbox I can say          Textbox.Text = "test" but not sure how to do it with a drop down list.

Comment: Value fields do not show in a combobox, the DisplayMember / DataTextFields do. [See Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1482528.aspx?Why+difference+in+DataValueField+and+DataTextField+)

Comment: `Combobox.Text = "YourText"`. You can also change the `SelectedIndex` to 0 (or whatever other index you want to show)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this is what I came up with - I guess also placed the information in the wrong spot before too! Combobox.Text = "yourText" worked ! - ty

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

   Dim TitleSearch As String = "Select distrubtorcode from titles where isbn = 986765654"

   Dim table As DataTable = Database.SelectRows(TitleSearch)

   Dim SQLUpdateDistrubtor =  "Select distinct distrubtorcode from titles "
   MyData = Database.SelectRows(SQLUpdateDistrubtor)
   For Each Row As DataRow In MyData.Rows
      UpdateDistributor.Items.Add(New ListItem((Row)("companyname"), (Row)("companyname")))
   Next

     If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        UpdateDistributor.text = table.rows(0)("distrubtorcode")
    End if 
End Sub
```